# Number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,k)$ where all four directions are allowed, using a specific number of steps

Tags: combinatorics, lattice-orders, random-walk, integer-lattices

It is well known that the number of paths from $(0,0)$ to $(n,k)$ in $\mathbb{N^2}$ with the set of steps $\{(1,0),(0,1)\}$ is ${n+k \choose k}$. This is the minimum number of steps needed to get to $(n,k)$.

Consider the step set:

$\;\;\;\;\;\;$  $\uparrow$

$\leftarrow\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;$  $\rightarrow$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;$    $\downarrow\;\;$

Where every step is one unit in that direction. I wonder: is it known how many paths there are from $(0,0)$ to $(n,k)$ with n+k+2 or even n+k+4 steps under these unit steps?

I mean, is there a closed form formula for these kind of paths with $2$, $4$ or $2r$ "extra" steps?

Comment: Are you allowed to revisit earlier points?

Comment: Yes, absolutely. The only restrictions are the ones stated, number of steps and the path is totally contained in $\mathbb{N^2}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am posting the answer in the interest of quality content and engaging the curiosity of the viewers who left wondering about the answer. I found the answer to my question after much reference hunting from paper to paper during the summer of 2014. The answer is: Yes, there is such a formula for $n+k+2$ and $n+k+4$, in fact the formula works for $n+k+t$ where $t$ is any number of extra steps, and there even is a formula for higher dimensions!!.

$$P_n^{++}((0,0)\rightarrow(c,d)):=\binom{n}{\frac{n+c-d}{2}}\binom{n+2}{\frac{n-c-d}{2}}-\binom{n+2}{\frac{n+c-d}{2}+1}\binom{n}{\frac{n-c-d}{2}-1}$$

Where $n$ is the total number of steps, so there are $n-c-d$ extra steps. For higher dimensions refer to the paper.

The details of the proof can be found in Richard Guy, Bruce E. Sagan and Christian Krattenthaler's paper titled [Lattice paths, reflections, & dimension-changing bijections](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~kratt/artikel/paths.html) . This is a dvi copy found in Sagan's website. The proof is ingenious and rather simple( once you see it, but not before.)

Answer (score 3):

For a path with $n+k+2r$ steps, if you have $n+i$ steps of $(1,0)$ you'll have $i$ steps of $(-1,0)$, $k+r-i$ steps of $(0,1)$ and $r-i$ steps of $0,-1)$, where $0 \le i \le r$.  Note that it doesn't matter in which order you take your steps.  So you just count the number of ways to choose $n+i$ elements out of $n+k+2r$, then $i$ out of the remaining $k+2r-i$, then $k+r-i$ of the remaining
$k+2r-2i$.  The total number of ways is
$$ \sum_{i=0}^r \dfrac{(n+k+2r)!}{(n+i)!i!(k+r-i)!(r-i)!} = {n+k+2\,r\choose k+r}{n+k+2\,r\choose r}$$

EDIT: Oops, this is using ${\mathbb Z}^2$, not ${\mathbb N}^2$.  If you require the path to stay in the first quadrant, that changes things.

Comment: By enumeration it is not so bad to calculate $(0,0)$ for a low $r$. For $r=2$ it seems your formula is wrong, I get $12$ and it should be $10.$

Comment: Sorry, I added instead of multiplying. You are correct, I do get $36.$ But, that is too many paths on $\mathbb{N^2}$ with 4 units steps as described above.

Comment: Your insight on $\mathbb{Z^2}$ is much appreciated. Please, leave your response for my reference. :)

Comment: This seems wrong for $\mathbb{Z}^2$. This counts the number of paths from the origin to where? $(n,k)$?

Comment: Robert check my post, I think you will appreciate it. :) Happy New Year.